# Efficient generation of permutation matrices in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, combinatorics

I'm trying to generate a 100-by-5 matrix where every line is a permutation of 1..100 (that is, every line is **5 random numbers from [1..100] without repetitions**).

So far I've only been able to do it iteratively with a for-loop. Is there a way to do it more efficiently (using fewer lines of code), without loops?

```
N = 100;
T = zeros(N, 5);

for i = 1:N
   T(i, :) = randperm(100, 5);
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let

```
N = 100; % desired number of rows
K = 5;   % desired number of columns
M = 100; % size of population to sample from
```

Here's an approach that's probably **fast**; but **memory-expensive**, as it generates an intermediate `M`×`N` matrix and then discards `N`-`K` rows:

```
[~, result] = sort(rand(N, M), 2);
result = result(:, 1:K);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is very little downside to using a loop here, at least in this minimal example. Indeed, it may well be the best-performing solution for MATLAB's execution engine. But perhaps you don't like assigning the temporary variable `i` or there are other advantages to vectorization in your non-minimal implementation. Consider this carefully before blindly implementing a solution.

You need to call `randperm` `N` times, but each call has no dependency on its position in the output. Without a loop index you will need something else to regulate the number of calls, but this can be just `N` empty cells `cell(N,1)`. You can use this cell array to evaluate a function that calls `randperm` but ignores the contents (or, rather, lack of contents) of the cells, and then reassemble the function outputs into one matrix with `cell2mat`:

```
T = cell2mat(cellfun(@(~) {randperm(100,5)}, cell(N,1)));
```